# Jasmine get spied on function not to call until some condition is true

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I would like a function I am spying on not execute until some condition is true.
Here is an example:

```
function openInfoDialog(id) {
    let scope = $scope.$new(true);
    scope.dataLoading = true;
    api.getData(id).then(data => {
        let processedData = process(data);
        scope.columns = processedData.columns;
        scope.data = processedData.data;
        scope.dataLoading = false;
    });
    ngDialog.open({
        //various dialog params,
        scope
    });
}
```

In my test I am trying to verify how the data is returned by the `process` function. The only way I can see to check that is to spy on `ngDialog.open` and check what is was called with.

However in my test `ngDialog` is being called before the `process` function finishes, meaning `scope.data` is undefined.

Is there any way I can tell `ngDialog` to wait until the `then` block is complete in the test? Or wait until scope.dataLoading is true.

To be clear, I do not want to change the functionality in my controller, I need to test what is currently written above.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spy on api.getData and mimic a promise return which is sync.

```
it('should process data', function () {
    var mockedDataObject = { ... };

    spyOn(api, 'getData').and.returnValue({
        then: function () { // Mimic a promise
            return mockedDataObject;
        }
    });

    openInfoDialog(123);

    expect(api.getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);

    expect(scope.columns).toEqual(whateveryouexpect)
    expect(scope.data).toEqual(whateveryouexpect)
    expect(scope.dataLoading).toEqual(whateveryouexpect)
});
```

P.S. you mentioned you want to

> verify how the data is returned by the process function

In order to do that appropriately, firstly bind the `process` function onto `scope`, so that it can be accessed from tests. Secondly, call that function directly and check what it returned. You are meant to test functionality in isolation.

```
it('should process data', function () {
    var mockedDataObject = { ... };

    var mockedProcessedData = scope.process(mockedDataObject);

    expect(mockedProcessedData.columns).toEqual(expectedcolumns);
    expect(mockedProcessedData.data).toEqual(expecteddata);
});
```

Comment: The process function is private, there is no need to make it public other than for tests. Wouldn't making a function available to controller scope purely for the sake of testing it be considered wrong? (Genuine question, if this acceptable practice it makes my life a LOT easier)

Comment: Not at all, AngularJS was built with testability in mind. That being said, the most correct way would be to have the `process` function in a service.

Comment: Okay, I'll simply test my openInfoDialog function calls api.getData and open Dialog, and then I can test the process function in separate specs. Thanks